# Pivot data from two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have two tables, Table_A is a workflow tracker as shown below :

**Table_A**

```
Unique_ID    Status    Decision
1234         Open      Accept 
5678         Closed    Reject
9112         Closed    Accept
3141         Open      Reject
```

Table_B contains some of the Unique ID's above, along with various warning messages that have been generated (up to a maximum of 4).

**Table_B**

```
Unique_ID    Warning_Code    Warning
1234         1               Description1
1234         2               Description2
3141         1               Description2
5678         1               Description3
5678         2               Description1
5678         3               Description3
```

I'd love to be able to pivot the data from Table_B to show ALL the Unique ID's from Table_A in rows, and have columns that show how many times an error appears for that ID, and importantly, what the error is. Expected result would be :

```
Unique_ID    Status    Decision    Warning_1     Warning_2     Warning_3      Warning_4
1234         Open      Accept      Description1  Description2      -              -
5678         Closed    Reject      Description3  Description1  Description3  Description4
9112         Closed    Accept           -             -            -              -    
3141         Open      Reject      Description3       -            -              -
```

I'm not sure if this kind of pivot is even possible with SQL, so any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

use  conditional aggregation with `case when expression`

```
select 
  a.Unique_ID,Status,Decision,
  max(case when Warning_Code=1 then Warning end) as Warning_1,
  max(case when Warning_Code=2 then Warning end) as Warning_2,
  max(case when Warning_Code=3 then Warning end) as Warning_3,
  max(case when Warning_Code=4 then Warning end) as Warning_4
from tableA a inner join tableB b on a.Unique_ID=b.Unique_ID
group by a.Unique_ID,Status,Decision
```

Answer (score 0):

use case when with aggregation

```
select Unique_ID,Status ,Decision,
max(case when Warning_Code=1 then Warning end) as waring1
max(case when Warning_Code=2 then Warning end) waring2,
max(case when Warning_Code=3 then Warning end) waring3
from tablea a join tableb b on a.Unique_ID=b.Unique_ID 
group by Unique_ID,Status ,Decision
```

Comment: congrats on SQL badge.

Answer (score 0):

It is basic pivot query, you only have to make left join, in case any row in `A` has no decisions in `B`:

```
select *
  from a left join b using (unique_id)
  pivot (max(warning) for warning_code in (1 w1, 2 w2, 3 w3, 4 w4))
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=37b9506aed7424d5242755c4ba194f64)</sup>**